# How to get all urls on a specific google search python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

So I am trying to create a program that gets all the urls on a google webpage search, and returns a list of them all in order of where they are on that page. So if its the top url on a google search page for "random", [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=random) link, then the first item in the list that should be returned should be "https://www.random.org/". This is due to it being the first link when you search random on google in the source code. I am using urllib3 and the re module because I do not really know how to use beautiful soup or lxml but if you can do this in beautiful soup and/or lxml that would also be fine. This is my code so far:

```
import urllib.request
import re

def find(start,end):

    urls = []

    with open('data.txt', 'r') as myFile:
        pass # Needs to append the every instance of all urls between the start and end inputs in data.txt

    # Returns all instances of urls between the start and end paramaters in data.txt

    return urls


def parse(query):

    # Creates the url with the query

    url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + query

    # Gets past googles attempt to block parsing

    headers = {}
    headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"

    # Fetches data

    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read()

    # Saves the source code in a txt file

    saveFile = open('data.txt','w')
    saveFile.write(str(respData))
    saveFile.close()

    # Finds the urls and returns them

    newUrl = find('<h3 class="r"><a href="','"')
    return newUrl

print(parse("random"))
```

**PROBLEM:** My problem is making the find() function work, I am not sure how to get the urls from the source code saved in data.txt and the variable respData, I want to do make this efficient so I was thinking of using regular expressions. However I am not sure how to get it to get the urls from the source code based on where the url starts (the class bit which is a parameter for the find function) and where it starts (the inverted comma which is another parameter for the find function).

**SIMPLIFIED PROBLEM:** Given some text `data` how would you create a list with **all instances** of some text in `data` between two strings `start` and `finish`. And how would you make this efficient for a large amount of data stored in `data` and then apply that to the find() function in my original code.

**NOTE:** Using python 3.6.3 therefore, I'm not using urllib2 instead urllib3. And if it is going to to take a long time to get every url on a google search webpage the first 10 urls are fine.

Comment: And what kind of problem are you facing?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the urls from the source code, my problem is doing the find() function and if you read the comment next to the pass you can see what I want it to do.

Comment: I will make that more clearer in the post now.

Comment: So you want to know how to read a file line by line and add that to a list?

Comment: no, i want to return a list with all the urls based on some data, and what all the urls start and end with. So the output for print(return("random")) will be a list like: [https://random.org, https://blabla.com] and so forth

Comment: You should really limit this question to a single problem and ask different questions for different problems if you can't find those questions already.

Comment: It is only one question. How to get all instances of some text in data between two strings start and end applied to my find() function.

Answer (score 0):

With beautiful soup, after urlopen

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#code snip

resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp)

for x in soup.findAll('a', {"class": "r"}):
    print(x)
```

I have not tested, but this is how you do the search in Beautiful soup

On a side note, using Regex to parse html can be tricky when going it alone.  Better to use Beautiful Soap 4 or Scrapy to handle the parsing for you.

Comment: Also you need a colon at the end of a for loop.

Comment: I want it to find all text in between <h3 class="r"><a href=" and " it does not do this, and just returns None and a warning from beautiful soup saying UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html5lib").